# Is it possible to access a value from a script with a function?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I need to save the email from this script:

```
<script>
  window.renderOptIn = function() {
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
      window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
        {
          "merchant_id": 0000,
          "order_id": "100101205",
          "email": "tester@example.com",
          "delivery_country": "XX",
          "estimated_delivery_date": "2021-09-03"
        });
    });
  }
</script>
```

Is there a way to do that? It's physically in the code but I can't think of a way to get it.

### Context:

It's e-commerce related. The script is on the "thank-you" page. I need to save the email to a variable so I can use it for google's enhanced conversion tracking.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to access?

Comment: If your `gapi.surveyoptin` expose elements passed to `render`, then yes. Else - no

Comment: The object is not visible outside of the function it's in. In fact, it's not even visible inside the function, since it's directly passed into the `render()` call. So, there is no *easy* way to get it. You could probably parse the script tag (undesirable) or overwrite the `render()` method (also undesirable).

Comment: The only way I can come to think would to regex this script tag, since you said it is "physically in the code", I guess you mean that the script is inline.

Comment: Are you sure the customer's email is hard-coded in your website?

Comment: The email is not hardcoded in the website, the only place you can find it is this code fragment I provided. It probably comes from the server.
Now I realise scrapping it with .innerText method is the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the document.scripts and filtering on content

Regular expression or split.

```js
const code = [...document.scripts].filter(script => script.textContent.includes('surveyoptin'))
const match = code[0].textContent.match(/(?:render\(.*\s+)({.*\s+)+/s)
const str = match[1].split(");")[0]; // forgot how to ignore trailing stuff after the group: );
console.log(str)
const obj = JSON.parse(str); // fails on 0000
console.log(obj.email)

// alternative - this is inflexible on spacing etc:

console.log(
  code[0]
  .textContent
  .split('"email": "')[1]
  .split('"')[0]
)
```

```html
<script src="x.js"></script>
<script>const survey = "Survey"; // dummy script</script>
<script>
  window.renderOptIn = function() {
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
      window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
        {
          "merchant_id": "0000",
          "order_id": "100101205",
          "email": "tester@example.com",
          "delivery_country": "XX",
          "estimated_delivery_date": "2021-09-03"
        });
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, especially for the 1st line which can target the right script even it it doesn't have any **id**, very usefull.
`const code = [...document.scripts].filter(script => script.textContent.includes('surveyoptin'))`
Somehow your entire script didn't work when I ran it in on the page (resulting in _Syntax Error: unexpected token , in JSON at JSON.parse_ ) but I synthesised your solution with that of @rahul-shah and it worked. Many thanks!

Comment: The 0000 is not valid number so that needs to be addressed somehow

Answer (score 0):

So you can access the script tag using a querySelector. It would be ideal if you could attach an id to the script tag so you can get it easily. If not, there is a work around to that as well.

You can access the content of the script tag using element.innerHTML.
Then, you would have to apply regex or string manipulation to get the exact snippet you are looking for.
For eg.

```
const script = document.querySelector("#script_id")
const scriptText = script.innerText
const emailString = scriptText.match(/"email":.*,/)[0]
const email = emailString.split(":")[1].trim().replace(/[,(\\")]/g,"")
```

This works. You may have to modify the parsing functions a bit. But I hope the approach is clear

P.S. This is a very hacky way of doing it and such code should be avoided as far as possible. But if you have to do it, I can't think of any other way.